# Pulling Column count and header text with auto generated columns in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I am rewriting one the functions within my team’s primary library and one of those functions is to export a Gridview to an Excel spread sheet.  I already have a function to export a DataSet to Excel, so all I need to do is convert a gridview to a DataSet.  No problem right?  All was well until I found that the GridView object’s columns collect is empty and the header text is null when using auto generated columns.

I know that MS has said that you surrender how the gridview renders that data, but I can’t find anything that shows how I might capture the column collection.  I’d like this Library to be as flexible as possible.

Here is my function as it stands now...

```
public static MemoryStream GridViewToXLSX(GridView Gridview, Options options = null)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        for (int i = 0; i < Gridview.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(Gridview.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < Gridview.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                dr[Gridview.Columns[j].HeaderText] = row.Cells[j].Text;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        return DataSetToXLSX(ds, options);
    }
```

Comment: Use dataset from grid.DataSource ! Use OleDbConnection

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alternatively you can try this sample code, instead of Column.count, you can count the number of   cells in the HeaderRow of the GridView.

This is just a sample, not actual code

```
GridViewRow headerRow = gv.HeaderRow; 
int count = headerRow.Cells.Count
```

Comment: While that helps with getting the number of columns, it doesn't help me get the header text.  Halfway there.

Comment: because you know the header cell index now then you can loop through on Cell index to get Header text, try this

Comment: Ah yes! there we go. Much appreciated.

Comment: Your welcome! more important that you are able to resolve that.